# Commands don't work in Git bash but work in Windows command

Tags: ruby, git, git-bash

I installed Ruby, and I installed git.

When I right-mouse click, I can run Git bash.

But commands like

```
git status
```

or

```
gem install ~~~
```

don't work there. But they perfectly work fine with Windows command.

But commands like

```
heroku login
```

doesn't work both in windows command and git bash. I get the error message

```
bash: heroku: command not found
```

Is there something that I need to connect git bash with these commands?

Comment: What version of git and ruby did you install? What error message do you see?

Comment: @VonC  command not found. I edited my question.

Comment: What version of git and ruby did you install? What is you path in those shell? (`echo $PATH` or `echo %PATH%`)

Comment: MINGW64 ? I see this from this git bash. Does this tell something about the version?

Comment: Simply type `git --version` in a dos session.

Comment: @VonC  It says 1.9.5.msysgit

Answer (score 0):

1.9.5 is now obsolete.

Uncompress [PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit\bin` to your `%PATH%`.
Also, call `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe` to test a bash session, in which git will be recognized.

Make sure your `%PATH%` also includes the path for ruby.

Comment: Thank you. Now when I type "git --version", it says 2.5.0.windows.1    I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\PortableGit\bin;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin" to system environment variable path. But still, in the git bash, commands like "gem install rails" and "heroku login" just result in "command not found". But they work perfectly in the usual command black box.

Comment: Weird. By the way, if I can open the usual command black box (not the git bash) just by clicking right-mouse-click at a certain folder and choosing "command", that will be awesome because I wouldn't need to type multiple "cd directory" every time I run it. Can I do this? Then well, this git bash error is not very a huge problem...

Comment: @user3123767 Try setting manually the `PATH` from within a git-bash.exe session: `echo $PATH`; `export PATH=$PATH:/C/path/to/...`